# How can I use Spring Batch Admin with Spring 3.2 and @Schedule annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I integrated Spring Batch Admin into my app, which uses Spring 3.2.

Now I try to annotate a method with `@Scheduled` and activate this with `<task:annotation-driven/>`.
When I launch the webapp I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Scheduled method 'removeInactiveExecutions'
found on bean target class 'SimpleJobService', but not found in any interface(s) for bean
JDK proxy. Either pull the method up to an interface or switch to subclass (CGLIB) proxies 
by setting proxy-target-class/proxyTargetClass attribute to 'true'
```

The `SimpleJobService` of Spring Batch Admin uses this annotation on a method.

In Spring 3.2. it seems, that there is no need to put cglib into the classpath and spring-asm is obsolete, too. I excluded the `spring-asm` dependency from spring-batch-integration.

Where can I set `proxy-target-class=true` (I already tried it on `<tx:annotation-config>` and `<aop:config>`?

How can I use `@Scheduled` in my application?

Comment: Is there an interface for the SimpleJobService?

Comment: Yes, its JobService. However, the annotated method is not member of the interface.

Comment: I found a raleted ticket in Springs Jira:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCHADM-126

But the advised solution doesn't work with Spring 3.2. Fortunately, I can answer my question, where to set the proxy-target-class: It should be on the task-namespace element, which is not supported by Spring at the moment.

Comment: how did you end up getting past this?

Comment: @Hendrik I worked around the problem with the task context of Spring. I created a XML file and use the `<task:scheduled-tasks>` element to create a scheduler on a bean e.g. `<task:scheduled ref="jobRunner" method="launchTheJob" cron="0 0 12 * * MON-FRI"/>`.

Answer (score 2):

Add execution-context.xml in META-INF\spring\batch\override, set proxy of SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean to target class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <!-- Original jobRepository missing read ${batch.isolationlevel} -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager" p:isolationLevelForCreate = "${batch.isolationlevel}"/>


    <!-- Original jobService conflicted with @EnableScheduling -->
    <bean id="jobService"
        class="org.springframework.batch.admin.service.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean">
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
        <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```